# Getting the number of documents returned to from a viewEntry

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have a panel on which I have defined a Domino view and called it viewEntry and attached it to a view in the current database. In the Data definition I have it set to filter by Category Names, all of which it does very nicely. Now I want to know how many documents the viewEntry contains. As I understand it viewEntry is a NotesXspViewEntry and I should be able to do something like viewEntry.getChildCount(). So I created a computedFiled inside the panelData with the formula viewEntry.getChildCount() but I get the error:
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=11: [TypeError] Error calling method 'getChildCount()' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.View [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.View: lotus.domino.View]'

So I think this is saying that viewEntry is a NotesView not a NotesXspEntry, guess I was wrong. Then the question still is how do I get a handle on the document count returned in the viewEntry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aiming one too high....

```
 NotesView -> ViewControl --> Entries
```

I wouldn't call the ViewControl "ViewEntry" confuses the matter very much... since it is rather an EntryCollection. The property you are looking for is `ViewControl.getRowCount()` The ViewControl does't "know" that it gets only a filtered result from the data source, so `ViewControl.getRowCount()` returns what the datasource delivered to the control.

Be careful: that method can be quite slow if you have lots of data.

Alternate thought (I'm guessing use cases :-) )...

Quite often we see the category being [selectable using a dropdown](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7UDMQS) - that might apply to your use case too. A nice "feature" would be to show the number of entries behind the category name. Something like:

```
   blue (27) | blue
   red (34) | red
   black (345) | black
```

In this case you want to use a ViewNavigator to retrieve the values upfront. Steal some [code](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9BUG9F?Open) for that.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: That will do the job, I use a view Navigator to get the values for the categories in my repeat then do the filter to display the actual data. The idea to display the count is good I might just add it.What I'm trying to do is that I have a pager for the repeat and if the getRowCount() is less than the row limit I want to hide the pager. Perhaps there is an easier way. Does the repeatControl have a property somewhere that tells it how many rows it has?

Comment: I'm going to re-post this as a different sort of question