# Does a Pager or Repeat Control expose the rowCount?

Tags: xpages

If I have on an Xpage a panel (say panelData) that has a data definition of a dominoView (say viewCollection) that is filtered and returns a group of documents. Then add a repeat control inside panelData (say repeatData) that is bound to viewCollection and the collection name is say rowData. Now add a Pager for repeatData. All works fine. 
Now the pager has to be able to query repeatData and get the number of rows contained within the repeat.  So my question is is there a way to get the rowCount directly from either repeatPager or repeatData without having to recompute the value.

stWissel suggests using viewCollection.getRowCount() here:

[Getting the number of documents returned to from a viewEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029453/getting-the-number-of-documents-returned-to-from-a-viewentry)

but says that there could be a significant performance hit if there are a lot of documents in the collection because this method recounts the documents, but the pager and the repeat laready knows how many documents there are in the collection. Is there a lower level property that is excessible from either the Pager or the Repeat that does not require recounting all the documents in the collection?

What I'm trying to do is hide the pager if the rowCount is greater than the rowLimit. I have added the rowLimit as a customProperty to the Custom Control then set the rowLimit of the repeat to compositeData.rowLimit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The View Container (ViewPanel, DataView etc) has the rows property that gives the number of rows to show at any one time. The dominoView will have the number of rows available to the pager, so you need to get a handle on that component, get its data model and query that. So `getComponent("dataView1").getDataModel().getRowCount()` will give you what you want without needing to query the underlying view twice.

I'd strongly recommend this blog post I wrote http://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-xpages-views/. It was a real revelation to understand how the various moving parts work.

Comment: So if I have direct access to "dataView1" then I do I get the same thing with dataView1.getDataModel().getRowCount() ? or do I have to get the component first?

Comment: I get the same results with both methods getComponent("dataView1").getRowCount() and getComponent("dataView1").getDataModel().getRowCount() for a viewpanel